# Conversion of for-loop with an if-condition into list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Is it possible to convert the for loop with an if-condition, in the given code, to a list comprehension?

```
    ListIndex = 0
    timeSeries = []
    Value = defaultValue
    dfLength = len(dfCont.index)

    for i in range(dfLength):
        if abs(dfCont.iloc[i, 0] - occurance[ListIndex]) < 0.0001:
            Value = discreteValues[ListIndex]
            ListIndex = ListIndex + 1
        timeSeries.append(Value)
```

I tried using standard definition to compress this for loop into list comprehension but it doesn't seem to work. Would it be possible to convert this for-loop into a list comprehension in the first place? And if yes, what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't believe you can express that as a list comprehension (at least, not without making it significantly worse to understand/debug).

The key part is that you're updating `Value` and `ListIndex` on some of the iterations, and needing those updated values to persist to future iterations.  That's not really how list comprehensions work, since they're meant to replace the `map()` function.  The basic form is:

```
[f(x) for x in y if g(x)]
```

Your output is a list of `f(x)` return values, and that can't depend on earlier values of `x` passed in unless `f` keeps global state (which is gross; don't do that).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need `ListIndex` variable since you can get it from `enumerate`

```
timeSeries = [discreteValues[idx] for idx, i in enumerate(dfLength) if abs(dfCont.iloc[i, 0] - occurance[ListIndex]) < 0.0001]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `enumerate` to get both index and value. Also, you can set default value using else

```
[discreteValues[ListIndex] if abs(dfCont.iloc[i, 0] - occurance[ListIndex]) < 0.0001 else defaultValue for ListIndex, i in enumerate(dfLength)]
```